# Unintended formatting using PHP DomDocument

Tags: php, domdocument, cdata

I am trying to include a formatted element in an XML document, using PHP's DomDocument class.

I wrote the following function:

```
function awstAddFormattedElement ($mySessionParams, $parentElement, $elementName, $elementValue) {
    $xmlDoc = $mySessionParams['xmlDoc'];

    $element = $xmlDoc->createElement($elementName,$elementValue);
    $element = $parentElement->appendChild($element);

    $myessionParams['element'] = $element;
    return $mySessionParams;
}
```

The problem is that when I call it, entities in the $elementValue are automatically encoded, and the service I'm calling is rejecting it.

```
$elementValue = '<![CDATA['.
                    '<p>blah, blah, blah.</p>'.
                ']]>';
```

So, when I do:

```
awstAddFormattedElement ($mySessionParams, $parentElement, 'FormattedContent', $elementValue)
```

I expect to see something like this in the resulting XML:

```
<FormattedContent><![CDATA[<p>blah, blah, blah.</p>]]></FormattedContent>
```

Instead, I'm getting the following:

```
<FormattedContent>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;blah, blah, blah.&lt;/p&gt;]]&gt;</FormattedContent>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CDATA sections, you have to use [`DOMDocument::createCDATASection`](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.createcdatasection.php), eg

```
$element = $xmlDoc->createElement($elementName);
$element->appendChild($xmlDoc->createCDATASection($elementValue));

$parentElement->appendChild($element);
```

Your `$elementValue` argument should only contain the raw string, eg

```
$elementValue = '<p>blah, blah, blah.</p>';
```